# Is it possible to use onTap with FirebaseAnimatedList

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i'm pretty new in Flutter. So i wanted to ask you guys, is it possible using FirebaseAnimatedList to make it pop another window when user presses the list item. I have a feeling that it not be possible to do it, would be great if someone could explain it.

```
 child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
    query: dbRef,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
        Animation<double> animation, int index) {
      Map contact = snapshot.value;
      return _buildContactItem(contact: contact);
    },
  ),
```

**Instance of onTap code snippet**

```
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ItemPage(uid: widget.uid)),
    );
  }, 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand u well, u want to make onPress method for each listItem?

just wrap your widget with Inkwell inside your itembuilder.

For example:

```
   _buildContactItem(Contact contact){
   return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
    context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ItemPage(uid: widget.uid)),
     );
    },

    child: yourChildWidgetsHere
   }
```

Try this, I hope it will help you!

Comment: Yes, thank you, you got me right. I wanted to make sure, in here 'child: yourChildWidgetsHere' there must be another widget? @BosS

Comment: Ok, finally worked out big thanks to you @BosS